# Can I forward recalculate a value in a pandas dataframe when a value has been reset, e.g. a water meter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to forward fill my water meter reading data when resets occur so that the data is clean for analysis. A reset is when the value in the next row is less than the previous one.

My python pandas dataframe looks like this:-

```
     water  
0    31031    
1    31037  
2    31038  
3    31043   
4    131   (system was reset)
5    223
6    331
7    412
...
```

It is possible that there are several resets of the water data in my pandas dataframe.

Research suggests that using for loops/iteration is not the best option with pandas dataframes so I am trying to avoid.

I would like to update the dataframe df so that the fact that the system was reset at index 4 is no longer visible and the water figures continue to cumulate.

e.g.

```
     water  
0    31031    
1    31037  
2    31038  
3    31043   
4    31174   # system reset to 0 so value should be 31043 + 131
5    31266   # continuing with the difference through to the end of df
6    31374
7    31445
...

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'water': [31031,31037,,31038,31043,131,223,331,412]})

df["waterreset"] = np.where(df["water"]-df["water"].shift(1)<0, df["water"] + df["water"].shift(1),df["water"])

print(df)
```

"waterreset" code line above only identifies the one line where the reset occurs and doesn't fill forward, plus I would rather use inplace=True to update the current dataframe.

Comment: How do we know there is a "reset"? Is it every 4th row?

Comment: Could be anywhere in the df, there are thousands of rows.  Basically it's when the water reading in the next row is less.

Comment: Ah, so the values are *should* be a cumulative value. What happens when the value is the same as the previous? should that be considered a reset?

Comment: Same value as previous is not a reset, just means that no water was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can find where the resets are, take the previous values, and add to the subsequence:

```
# resets
resets = df.water.diff().le(0)

# reading at resets
# cumsum is used to accumulate readings
readings = df.water.shift().where(resets).fillna(0).cumsum()

df.water += readings
```

Output:

```
     water
0  31031.0
1  31037.0
2  31038.0
3  31043.0
4  31174.0
5  31266.0
6  31374.0
7  31455.0
```

Comment: Note that the output is a little different from your expected output. Plz verify if this is what you need.

Comment: The readings in your output are correct; I will edit my expected output.

Comment: Note that `le` stands for less-than-or-equal, so `.diff().le(0)` is also true for a difference of 0. (Workaround might be using `.le(-1)`)